# JIRA Plugin to Extend Capabilities of "Link to Issue" Dialog

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am facing a problem in JIRA Plugin to Extend Capabilities of "Link to Issue" Dialog, I have found you have worked on similar kind of feature with reference post given below .

Reference from Post : https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/151130/jira-plugin-to-extend-capabilities-of-link-to-issue-dialog?page=1#261582

I have been trying the same thing today but i am getting errors in IDE for import com.atlassian.jira.web.action.issue.AbstractIssueLinkAction; .

The steps i have followed are .

Install Jira SDK with installer sdk-installer-4.2.13 .

Create Jira 5 plugin with command "atlas-create-jira5-plugin"

create eclipse configureation for plugin clreated with commnd "atlas-create-jira5-plugin"

Import the project in eclipse .

Copy the .Java files from the shamid project from bitbucket. for plugin downloded and try to resolve the dependencies of compilation error .

Can you please help me resolve this issue. I am not able to compile this code .

The error in IDE is due to class missing in my build path .

Answer (score 0):

did you enabled following module on pom.xml?

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

can you share your pom.xml?

once you change the your pom.xml don't forgot to run the following commands
**atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse**